# How to fix error 500 Soap With python Zeep?

Tags: python-3.x, soap, soap-client, flask-restful, zeep

i having this error when i make the request to the Soap Server, i check all the parameter requested but give me the same error i need help!

```
Request from server:

     `message = {
        'channel': {
            'type': 'f12',
            'name': 'ESP',
            'version': '5500'
        },
        'foreign_remote_system': {
            'identifier': 'W',
            'reference_no': '82',
            'counter_id': 'DV'
        },
        'payment_transaction': {
            'payment_details': {
                'destination_country_currency': {
                    'iso_code': {
                        'country_code': 'DO',
                        'currency_code': currency_code
                    }
                }
            },
            'mtcn': mtcn
        }
    }   `        

Origial request WSDL XML:
`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xrsi="http://www.westernunion.com/schema/xrsi">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<xrsi:receive-money-search-request>
<channel>
<type>H</type>
<name>P</name>
<version>00</version>
</channel>
<foreign_remote_system>
<identifier>WG</identifier>
<reference_no>82</reference_no>
<counter_id>D</counter_id>
</foreign_remote_system>
<payment_transaction>
<payment_details>
<destination_country_currency>
<iso_code>
<country_code>u</country_code>
<currency_code>P</currency_code>
</iso_code>
</destination_country_currency>
</payment_details>
<mtcn>9</mtcn>
</payment_transaction>
</xrsi:receive-money-search-request>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`

Error:

  

      `zeep.transports: Loading remote data from: https://wugateway2pi.westernunion.net?wsdl
        ERROR:root:Exception occurred: Invalid XML content received (Document is empty, line 1, column 1)
        127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jul/2023 09:07:55] "POST /receive_money/search/DOP/9735896579 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
        INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jul/2023 09:07:55] "POST /receive_money/search/DOP/9735896579 HTTP/1.1" 500 -`
```

**When sending the parameters it gives me an error that says that a parameter is missing taking into account that all the parameters are sent correctly because I have already verified this part but even so the response tells me the same**